# Color in python's colorama not unset even with Fore.RESET

Tags: python, colorama

I use colorama to stylize the output of *tqdm* in a way similar to this:

`tqdm.pandas(f'{Fore.CYAN}some prefix text {Fore.RESET} some text {Fore.MAGENTA} Some message')`

`some prefix text` is cyan, and `Some message` is magenta, but `some text` is somehow **red**! I actually need it to be white, i.e. the general color of the console, but as you probably know `Fore.WHITE` is not exactly white but somewhat gray, so it won't work.

Could anybody explain how this works, why I get it red, and what can I do here? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use `Style.RESET_ALL` from the Style object instead of `Fore.RESET`

The solution would look like this:

```
from colorama import Fore, Style

tqdm.pandas(f'{Fore.CYAN}some prefix text {Style.RESET_ALL} some text {Fore.MAGENTA} Some message {Style.RESET_ALL}')
```

Comment: Didn't work, the same red stuff, unfortunately. Thank you anyway! I guess that's something related to tqdm, maybe its default style is red, but it seems like it's there's no parameter for it. Thanks!

Comment: Aw, sry dude thought this would fix your issues.